# Xcode Documentation Generator

Tags: xcode, documentation-generation, code-documentation

I've looked at Headerdoc and Doxygen for documenting source code, but they both seem to need the developer to do most of the leg-work first. In Visual Studio, typing `\\\` generates the skeleton for documentation including the parameters expected by a method. There's also [Ghostdoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) which guesses what the method does based on its name and parameters. Is there anything similar for Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc), which creates a variety of documentation from comments in your source, docsets, html that looks just like the Apple docs.

Comment: But that doesn't appear to generate the documentation skeleton. I'm not looking to generate HTML documentation, just source code documentation.

Comment: I don't think so. If you don't write it I don't know of anything that would extract it from the uncommented source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**VVDocumenter**](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) plugin, it's a very handy plugin for XCode documentation.

After that you can find the method (or any code) you want to document to, and type in `///`, the document will be generated for you and all params and return will be extracted into a Javadoc style, which is compatible with **Appledoc**, **Doxygen** and **HeaderDoc**. You can just fill the inline placeholder tokens to finish your document.

Answer (score 0):

Download the XCode package manager: [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/) which can be done easily with the following command:

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/master/Scripts/install.sh | sh
```

Restart XCode and you will find a new option in the Window toolbar menu labed 'Package Manager'.  You can then install [VVDocumenter](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) from there.

Once you install VVDocumenter you'll need to restart XCode again, but after you reload Xcode you can then type /// to get help writing comments which will later be used to write your documentation.